# Pie chart colors no longer setting

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Out of the blue, my charts no longer are set to the colors specified, as well as no longer have a transparent background.

No code changes occurred, which is all the more frustrating.

Code:

```
let chartBuilder = data.newChart();
  chartBuilder.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
              .addRange(data.getRange("A2:A4"))
              .setOption('width', 33)
              .setOption('height', 33)
              .setOption('colors', ["#A5D6A7", "#B4A7D6", "#81D4FA"])
              .setOption('backgroundColor.fillOpacity', 0) 
              .setPosition(1, 1, 0, 0);
  data.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
```

Test (Chart should appear Green/Purple/Blue):

```
function Test() {
// Insert test sheet.
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet("Test"); 
   const s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
// Insert test data.
   s.getRange("A1:A3").setValues([[33], [33], [33]]);
// Build chart.
   let chartBuilder = s.newChart();
   chartBuilder.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
               .addRange(s.getRange("A1:A3"))
               .setOption('width', 33)
               .setOption('height', 33)
               .setOption('colors', ["#A5D6A7", "#B4A7D6", "#81D4FA"])
               .setOption('backgroundColor.fillOpacity', 0) 
               .setPosition(1, 1, 0, 0);
   s.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
// Roadblock before deletion.
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Check result.", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
// Delete test sheet.
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().deleteSheet(s);
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me... Have you tried to hard-reset the page?

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify the colors, updating now. Does the chart appear green/purple/blue?

Comment: Yes. [See my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wRjx.png)

Comment: Do you get any error ? Put `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after you insert the chart.

Comment: No errors, flush doesn't get it to work either. Truly bizarre

Comment: Try making a new spreadsheet and try there. Let's see if it is file-specific.